# Why my page gets refresh while deleting image on 'product edit page'?

Tags: ajax, laravel, image, product

**VIEW FILE**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>Other Images</label>
        <div class="input-group control-group img_div form-group" >
        <input type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn"> 
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-add-more" type="button">Add</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div>@foreach($image as $image)
        <p><img src="{{asset('/files/'.$image->images)}}" height="50px" id="{{$image->id}}" class="photo"/>
        <button class="removeimg" data-id="{{$image->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">Remove</button></p>
        @endforeach
        </div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.removeimg',function(){
        var confirmation = confirm("are you sure to remove this record?");
        if (confirmation) {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        // console.log(id)
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        var $obj = $(this);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "{{ url('image/delete') }}/"+id,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function (res)
            {
                // $(this).parents('.photo').remove();
                $obj.parents('.photo').remove();
                console.log("it Work", res);
            }
        });
        console.log("It failed");
    }
    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function imgdelete($id){
        Image::find($id)->delete($id);
        return response()->json([
            'success'=> 'Image deleted successfully!'
        ]);
    }
```

When I delete the image, page gets redirected to product listing. Page should not get refresh when I delete the image. Can you please help me with correction?? NOTE: This process takes place on editproduct page.

Comment: It's a guess: But I thought that by default a `<button>` is a submit button. Is this button in a form on you page? If so, that could be the cause of your refreshing error. 
Try changing your button in a `<div>` or someting.

Comment: @Ruub I tried that but still page gets redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default event for the button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeimg',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    .....
});
```

Comment: Image gets deleted but on browser, it shows result after refreshing the page

Comment: Basically the button cannot refresh the page with this code... is the button inside an element that has a click event (that refreshes the page) ?

Comment: Button itself has a class, which gets triggered on click event. 
<button class="removeimg" data-id="{{$image->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">Remove</button></p>

Comment: Yes, but that is the event in this function. this does not refresh the page. If one of the ancestors is a `a` tag for example, it will follow the link (or another element that has a click event)